# getJSON callback not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

I need to do a cross domain request, and I have a problem with getJSON.

```
$.getJSON("http://usr:pwd@10.0.1.xx/cgi-bin/remote/request.cgi?m=json&r=grp&fn=getvalue&alias=1/3/51&callback=?",
        function(result) {
            alert('hi');
        });
```

The callback does not fire, i.e. I do not get the alert. If I paste the http:// link in a browser window, I get the desired result. It is a plain number, in this case `2`. I could also set the request to xml, in which case the result in the browser window is `<value>2</value>`. If someone could tell me what's wrong with my getJSON that would be great.

Many thanks and best regards

Comment: have you included the ajax scripts?

Comment: When you are saying that you are getting the desired result if you paste this link in your browser, could you please show this result here? Do you get a valid JSONP response? Also don't forget to replace the `?` in the callback parameter with a meaningful function name when pasting the url in your browser.

Comment: Darin, the result in the browser is a simple number, in this case a 2. Source code shows the plain number, nothing else.

Comment: Chain on a `fail` method and see what the error is

Comment: Ramesh, I unfortunately cannot follow.

Comment: Darin, I just removed the "&callback=?" from the url and put it in the browser window, then I get 2 as result.

Comment: Yes, but that's very far from any valid JSONP response. So don't remove the `&callback=?` parameter from the url when pasting in your browser, just replace it with some value: `&callback=foobar`. And then show us the output. It should look like this: `foobar(SOME_JSON)`. If the output doesn't look like this in your browser then this explains why your code isn't working. The endpoint you are trying to consume doesn't appear to support JSONP.

Comment: Darin, the result unfortunately is still a simple and plain '2'. So I would have to talk to the programmer of the unit I'm trying to access. Do you see a way in using XML, where I get '<value>2</value> as result?

Comment: No, you cannot use `$.getJSON` if your remote endpoint doesn't support JSONP or CORS. You can use XML only with CORS. But once again that's something you should check with the authors of this endpoint.

Comment: Darin, thank you very much for your help. I will check with the manufacturer if he can include JSONP.

Answer (score 1):

You might have an issue with your JSON. This is taken from the docs.

> Important: As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error,
>   the request will usually fail silently. Avoid frequent hand-editing of
>   JSON data for this reason. JSON is a data-interchange format with
>   syntax rules that are stricter than those of JavaScript's object
>   literal notation. For example, all strings represented in JSON,
>   whether they are properties or values, must be enclosed in
>   double-quotes. For details on the JSON format, see http://json.org/.

source:

```
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/
```

to have more control over error handling use `$.ajax`

you can check your JSON here http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the remote endpoint you are trying to call doesn't support JSONP or CORS. This can be seen in the console output of your browser or by pasting the url directly and replacing the `&callback=?` parameter with `&callback=somevalue`.

In order to be able to make cross domain AJAX calls the remote endpoint must support CORS or JSONP. You should probably contact the authors of this endpoint for enabling one of those if you want to be able to consume them with AJAX.